# Cannot resolve symbol 'Fetch' for any request of FilesResource

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upgrade to [Google Drive .NET API 1.3](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/ReleaseNotes#Version_1.3_%28beta%29). But it seems they have removed Fetch() method for all file requests. So, I have "Cannot resolve symbol 'Fetch'" errors in code like this:

```
DriveService service = GetDriveService();
var request = service.Files.Get(id);
var response = request.Fetch();
```

Is there any other way to work with Google Drive files and folders?

Comment: Alexey, what're the assembly versions of dlls you reference? I'm using 1.3.0.15233 and `Fetch` exists.

Comment: Right, it was incorrect assembly in the project. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of the Google APIs .NET client library still implements a Fetch method Request objects. Following snippet/your snippet is a valid sample:

```
DriveService service = GetDriveService();
request = service.Files.Get(id).Fetch();
```